# How do I display an Image (from URL) in Tkinter

Tags: python, image, url, tkinter

I want to display an image from a URL in Tkinter.
This is my current function:

```py
def getImageFromURL(url):
    print('hai')
    raw_data = urlopen(url).read()
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    return image
```

And the code where I am using this function is:

```py
print(imgJSON[currentIndex])
img = getImageFromURL(imgJSON[currentIndex])
imagelab = tk.Label(self, image=img)
imagelab.image = img
imagelab.pack()
```

However, the code is making the tkinter window crash (Not Responding), but there are no errors. How would I fix this?

Comment: Probably because it takes time to download the image, run it on a separate thread.

Comment: @CoolCloud How would I make it so it waits for the download to finish?

Answer (score 1):

You can use thread to fetch the image from internet and use tkinter virtual event to notify the tkinter application when the image has been loaded.

Below is an example code:

```py
import threading
import tkinter as tk
from urllib.request import urlopen
from PIL import ImageTk

def getImageFromURL(url, controller):
    print('hai')
    try:
        controller.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=urlopen(url))
        # notify controller that image has been downloaded
        controller.event_generate("<<ImageLoaded>>")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.imagelab = tk.Label(self, text="Loading image from internet ...", width=50, height=5)
        self.imagelab.pack()

        self.bind("<<ImageLoaded>>", self.on_image_loaded)

        # start a thread to fetch the image
        url = "https://batman-news.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Justice-League-Superman-Banner.jpg"
        threading.Thread(target=getImageFromURL, args=(url, self)).start()

    def on_image_loaded(self, event):
        self.imagelab.config(image=self.image, width=self.image.width(), height=self.image.height())

App().mainloop()
```

Comment: Still goes to the not responding state :I

Comment: It works fine in my two Windows machines.  Can you provide the image URL for testing?

Comment: Okay so I found the issue, I am trying to fix it right now.

Comment: Ok so @acw1668 my problem is a for loop, it is looping a global list of image URLs and changing the image every 3 seconds until the list is empty.